# How do I interpret the boundedness in this space?

Tags: functional-analysis, bochner-spaces

As I was reading the article [Non linear elliptic and parabolic equations involving measure data](https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/0022123689900050), I came across with the following:

> the sequence $\{f_n \}$ is bounded in the space
>   $L^1(0,T;W^{-1,s})+L^1(0,T;L^1)$,

where $W^{-1,s}$ denotes the usual Sobolev space.

What does this mean exactly? I thought a possible interpretation is:

Consider $\{g_n\} \in L^1(0,T;L^1)$ then $f_n -g_n$ is bounded in $L^1(0,T;W^{-1,s})$

Is this true?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If $X$, $Y$ are Banach spaces, which continuously embed into some Hausdorff topological vector space $Z$, then
$$
X+Y=\{h\in Z\mid \exists f\in X,\,g\in Y\colon h=f+g\}
$$
and
$$
\|h\|_{X+Y}=\inf\{\|f\|_X+\|g\|_Y\mid f\in X,g\in Y,h=f+g\}.
$$
Boundedness in $X+Y$ then has the usual meaning.

The choice of $Z$ does not matter and is often swept under the rug. In your case you could take for $Z$ something like $L^1(0,T;L^1+W^{-1,s})$, which leaves with another sum of Banach spaces. For these you can use the embeddings $L^1, W^{-1,s}\hookrightarrow \mathcal{D}^\prime$.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your answer. However I don't get the last sentence you wrote. How can I use these embeddings?

Comment: I gave you a space $Z$ for $X=L^1(0,T;W^{-1,s})$ and $Y=L^1(0,T;L^1)$, namely $Z=L^1(0,T;L^1+W^{-1,s})$. But this space again involves the sum of the Banach spaces $\tilde X=W^{-1,s}$ and $\tilde Y=L^1$. I suggested to take $\tilde Z=\mathcal{D}^\prime$ for the sum of $\tilde X$ and $\tilde Y$.

Comment: Oh of course! So then $f_n$ is bounded in $L^1(0,T; \mathcal D')$?

Comment: It's not even clear how to define $L^1(0,T;\mathcal{D}^\prime)$ - since $\mathcal{D}^\prime$ is not a normed space, which quantity should be integrable over $(0,T)$?